# Jquery Bind,Unbind

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am binding some click events to some images I have.When one of them is clicked I want to disable all of the images then after two seconds add back the same click event.

I have the following so far:

```
 $('#pagination img').each(function(index){
        $( this ).bind ("click",function(){
               pageClick = true;
               pagendex = index*9;
           clearInterval(progresstracker);

             $("#progressbar").progressbar( "option", "value", 0);
             numSecondsPassed=0;
             $('#pagination img').each(function(index){
                $(this).unbind('click');

             });

            // alert("Page Index" + pageIndex);
              rotateImage();

             }).mouseover(function(){
                  $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
            });
        });
```

I am unbinding them and that works.But I need to after two seconds bind them back to the click event with the same variables and unbinding again.Basically when they click unbind for 2 seconds then bind back rinse repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to reschedule the binding 2 seconds after the unbind has occured. This would probably mean extracting the function that binds / unbinds.

---

Just from the top of my head, I was thinking of something like :

```
var bindAll = function () {
  $("...").each(function (index, item) {
     item.bind("click", function (event) {
          // ... do your work 
          unbindAll();
     });
};

var undbindAll = function () {
     $("...").unbind('click');
     setTimeout(bindAll, 2000);
}
```

Now this assumes that you want to unbind the event for all the images, have I understood right ? Sorry If I missed something or this does not work in your case...

Comment: I tried using a timeout and inside the function of setTimeout() I put the exact same code as above this did not work as seemed like spaghetti code to me. Do you have an example?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a var for the function that binds the event, and in the sub-function that undbinds, call setTimeout with the same function (which is now possible since the function has a name). Now since you're using it in an iterator it might not be the exact same code you wrote, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't do unbind, as you can make global variable, that tracks, if you can click button or not like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttonClickable = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        if (buttonClickable)
        {
            $("body").append($(this).text());
            buttonClickable = false;
            setTimeout("buttonClickable = true; alert('passed');",2000);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button">Button1</div>
<div class="button">Button2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great solution and alot cleaner than all that unbinding mess.

Comment: and much faster than iterating though list TWICE each time you click